# Is rc.local the best place to add a pon start and network routing change?

Tags: networking, dhcp

I've [followed this guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/getting-started-super-sim-raspberry-pi-waveshare-4g-hat#software-setup) to get a 4G hat networked with my pi zero, and everything seems fine. I'm able to ping out once pon has started in the background and a route has been added.

What I want is for the pi to boot and for pon to be running already, and the route to be already added.

I'm currently doing this in the rc.local file, but I'm pretty sure it's quite a dirty approach:

```
sleep 20
sudo pon &
sleep 20
sudo route add -net "0.0.0.0" ppp0

exit 0
```

Perhaps interfaces or similar? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How I did it was to create two systemd services and a change to the routing table:

1. `4gpon.service` used to start pon in the background:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=4G hat networing

   [Service]
   Type=forking
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/pon
   ExecStop=/usr/bin/poff
   Restart=always

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. Updating the routing table to enable ppp0 by default

   ```
   sudo ip route delete default
   sudo ip route add default dev ppp0
   ```

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces.d/ppp0

   # add:
   auto ppp0
   iface ppp0 inet provider
   up ip route add default dev ppp0
   ```

   Then in addition [to the values defined here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/getting-started-super-sim-raspberry-pi-waveshare-4g-hat#4-connect-to-the-internet) for this file, add this one too:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/ppp/peers/provider

   # add at bottom:
   replacedefaultroute
   ```
3. The `garage-motion.service` that calls the python upon knowing the first service is up

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Motion detector service
   After=network.target network-online.target 4gpon.service

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   Environment="AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=***your-region***"
   Environment="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=***your-key***"
   Environment="AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=***your-secret-key***"
   ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/pi/projects/garage-motion/venv/python3 /home/pi/projects/garage-motion/venv/garage-motion.ph --serve-in-foreground'
   Restart=on-abort

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`rc.local` has been *deprecated* for a while now. It *might* work, but I wouldn't depend on it. To start a service at boot time, you have two options:

1. Use `systemd` to [start a service at boot time](https://www.howtogeek.com/687970/how-to-run-a-linux-program-at-startup-with-systemd/)
2. Use root's `crontab` to start `@reboot`

The tradeoff between `systemd` and `cron` is this: **`cron` is easier, `systemd` gives you more control**. IOW, you'll need to invest some time to learn `systemd` before you can use it effectively.

##### Steps for the `cron` approach:

1. Use the `root crontab`:

```bash
$ sudo crontab -e

# this will open your default editor with the existing `crontab`
# add this line, or an equivalent script instead of singleton commands:

@reboot sleep 20 && /path/to/pon && sleep 20 && route add -net "0.0.0.0" ppp0 >> /home/pi/ponlog.txt 2>&1
```

2. Save the file & exit the editor
3. Re-boot your Pi. Check the logfile at `/home/pi/ponlog.txt` for any messages & troubleshoot if required.

Comment: I didn't know rc.local functionality was deprecated. Thanks for the headsup!